# Detect backslash in img src with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

**EDIT: THIS POST IS FIXED, READ MORE DOWN FOR MORE HELP**

I have this diferents regular expressions:

```
var rex=new RegExp('<img.*?src="(.*?\/([^/"]*))".*?>', 'g')
var rex=new RegExp('<img [^>]*src="([^>"]+\/([^>"]+))"[^>]*?>', 'g')
var rex=new RegExp('<img.*?src="([^">]*\/([^">]*?))".*?>', 'g')
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
After  : <img [^>]*src="([^>"]+\\/([^>"]+))"[^>]*?>  
After  : <img.*?src="(.*?\\/([^\/"]*))".*?>
After  : <img.*?src="([^">]*\\/([^">]*?))".*?>
```

**SOLUTION:**

***When i declare the url the string no detect the "\" because no is escaped***

And this URL ( for example):

var  str = `'<img src="file:///C:\DOCUME~1\user\CONFIG~1\Temp\msohtml1\02\clip_image002.jpg" style="float:left; height:145px; width:193px" />';`

BUT when i declare the "str" no have the "\", how i can resolve that? i can't manual because this strings come automatic.

I use this while for push the URL in a array

```
var m,urls = [];
    while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
            urls.push( m[1] );
        }
            alert( urls );
```

i use all the regulars expressions but they return all time the same text:

```
file:///C:DOCUME~1cCanadasCONFIG~1Tempmsohtml1clip_image002.jpg
```

I know it's because the regular expression not detect the backslash, but i don't know where or how can i write the regular expression for that.

**SECOND PROBLEM**

EXAMPLE:
 I have this text in one string:

> Blockquote
>
> `<img src="file:///C:\DOCUME~1\cCanadas\CONFIG~1\Temp\msohtml1\01\clip_image002.jpg" style="float:left; height:145px; width:193px"></a></a><img src="file:///C:\DOCUME~1\cCanadas\CONFIG~1\Temp\msohtml1\01\clip_image004.jpg" style="float:left; height:192px; width:256px">`Ut elementum tempor quam, vel accumsan quam interdum nec. Quisque porta urna convallis, posuere diam in, sodales quam. Mauris ligula magna, sollicitudin id egestas at, pharetra eget erat. Quisque dignissim libero in lectus vestibulum commodo. Nunc vel augue augue. Sed vel magna egestas, laoreet nulla nec, aliquet velit. Quisque augue quam, eleifend non sollicitudin sit amet, vestibulum a nulla. Fusce pulvinar diam dapibus nunc posuere, at

How I can detect the SRC of IMG and change your backslashes by forward slashes?

Would appreciate your help!
Thank you very much!

P.d: If you can write the answer in JavaScript, but if you know other no problem for me-

Comment: looks like str doesn't fill correctly, you should escape backslash symbol, else you will get string like that. Try to display str after you assign it (`var str= ...; alert(str)`)

Comment: It is true, how I can do that automatically? What I want is to detect a src in a text and then replace them with others that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the `\` characters:

> ```
> Before : <img [^>]*src="([^>"]+\/([^>"]+))"[^>]*?>
> After  : <img [^>]*src="([^>"]+\\/([^>"]+))"[^>]*?>
>
> Before : <img.*?src="(.*?\/([^/"]*))".*?>
> After  : <img.*?src="(.*?\\/([^\/"]*))".*?>
>
> Before : <img.*?src="([^">]*\/([^">]*?))".*?>
> After  : <img.*?src="([^">]*\\/([^">]*?))".*?>
> ```

Comment: Now works with the indication of @loentar, you know hoy i can i escape automatic the urls of src in img?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean. An example might help.